# USB not usable anymore: RAW, Drive not found, not able to format etc

Tags: usb, raw

I had a USB and I converted it to bootable with ZorinOS. Now, when I get the USB, I got a d: directory not found, RAW sys files and Windows could not format errors. How to get the USB to work again?

I tried formatting and chkdsk but did not work.